# Difference between draw=none and draw opacity=0 (also for fill=none and fill opacity=0)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, transparency

What is the difference between the TikZ key-value pairs `draw=none` and `draw opacity=0`?  Are they functionally equivalent, or are there situations in which one should be preferred over another?  Similarly, what is the difference between `fill=none` and `fill opacity=0`?

Comment: I once had a case where I wanted to print 2 versions of a document: with and without labels. The first thing I did was `text opacity=0`. Although nothing was visible in the PDF file, fractions of the labels appeared in the printed version, so be careful ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`draw=none` (which is equal to `\path` command) actually causes TikZ to throw away the constructed path <strike>and the bounding box is not disturbed</strike> (Nonsense, it does change the bounding box but only `line width` is ignored. Thanks to @Fritz for catching this stupidity).

`draw opacity=0` however causes the path to be drawn with no ink so the bounding box gets updated with `line width` option in effect, so the line style matters for the bounding box calculation.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\draw[opacity=0,line width=1cm] (0,0) rectangle (3,3); % Enlarge the bounding box 

\pgfsetlinewidth{5cm}     % this has no effect
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4cm}{4cm}} % this updates the known max x,y coordinates!!
\pgfusepath{}                       % even though it's thrown away. 

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10cm}{10cm}} % Nothing happens
\pgfusepath{}
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}


\draw[dashed,thin] (current bounding box.north east) rectangle (current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Both answers are great -- just what I was looking for.  I decided to accept @percusse's answer only because I was originally slightly more interested in `draw`; I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: The beginning of this answer _"draw=none [...] causes TikZ to throw away the constructed path and the bounding box is not disturbed"_ is a bit misleading. The bounding box is indeed disturbed, if the _path_ itself (not the `line width`) protrudes from the bounding box. In your example `\path[line width=4cm] (0,0) rectangle (3,6);` would actually modify the bounding box, despite it not drawing. Thus the only difference between `draw=none` and `draw opacity=0` is that the line width has no effect with the former. For "hypothetical curves" you would use the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment.

Comment: @Fritz It's not misleading, it's flat out wrong :) Apparently, I didn't do enough experiments and jumped to conclusions. Thanks for the catch. I'll update it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 13):

`filling opacity` applies not only to filling operations, but also to also applies to text and images; the following example shows a case in which `fill=none` and `fill opacity=0` (I actually used `fill opacity=0.2` just to make the text visible) produce different results; `fill=none` has no effect on the node label, but `fill opacity=<value>` will affect the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[olive] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\node[fill opacity=0.2] at (3,2) {\huge B};
\node[fill=none] at (0,0) {\huge A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  It seems like a strange design choice to have `fill opacity` also affect the text opacity; why not leave that altogether to `text opacity`?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung no; they are not completely equivalent; I was composing some examples, but **percusse** has answered this part now.