# tikz: construct a phantom path

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I construct a path (curve, line) but not draw it?

For example, I want to construct the following path

```
\draw[name path = phantom] plot coordinates {
 (0, 2)
 (2, 5)
 (3, 7)
} ;
```

but do not want the actual line shown.

Comment: Use `\path` instead of `\draw`

Comment: @CarLaTeX Want to write an answer? You can mention `draw=none` and `opacity=0` as well, if you like, and possibly refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67711/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\draw` actually is a shortcut for `\path[draw]`, if you remove the `draw` option, and write only

```
\path
```

you'll have a path that is not drawn, even though TikZ will take into account its dimensions.

Possible alternatives are:

```
\draw[draw=none]
```

(which is exactly equal to a `\path` command) where you say to draw a path without any color, or

```
\draw[opacity=0]
```

where you say to draw a transparent path.
For a detailed explanation of the difference, see:
[Difference between draw=none and draw opacity=0 (also for fill=none and fill opacity=0)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67711/difference-between-draw-none-and-draw-opacity-0-also-for-fill-none-and-fill-opa)

Here is an MWE with the various options, I've put a frame around the `tikzpicture`s just to show that, even if the paths aren't drawn, their dimensions are taken into account.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
    This is your command:

    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[name path = phantom] plot coordinates {
                (0, 2)
                (2, 5)
                (3, 7)
            }; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{framed}

    This is with \texttt{\textbackslash path} only:

    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path plot coordinates {
                (0, 2)
                (2, 5)
                (3, 7)
            } ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{framed}
    \newpage
    This is with \texttt{\textbackslash draw[draw=none]}:

    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[draw=none] plot coordinates {
            (0, 2)
            (2, 5)
            (3, 7)
            } ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{framed}

    This is with \texttt{\textbackslash draw[opacity=0]}:
    \begin{framed}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[opacity=0] plot coordinates {
                (0, 2)
                (2, 5)
                (3, 7)
            } ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An extension to the [list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404992/16967) of CarLaTeX.

### Discard layer

The source code `TDS:tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex`
reveals a special layer that is discarded (it is not documented in the TikZ manual 3.0.1a):

```
\def\pgfdiscardlayername{discard}

\def\pgfonlayer@assert@is@active{%
  \ifx\pgfonlayer@name\pgfdiscardlayername
     % this special layer name can be used as /dev/null without
   % warning.
...
```

The next file intersects the plot of the question with a circle, adds a node in the center and draws a line from the intersection points to the left and right of the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (2, 5) node[draw] (hw) {Hello World};
  \draw[name path=phantom] plot coordinates {
    (0, 2)
    (2, 5)
    (3, 7)
  };
  \draw[name path=circle] (2, 5) circle[radius=2];
  \draw[name intersections={of=phantom and circle}]
    (intersection-1) -- (hw.south west)
    -- (hw.north east) -- (intersection-2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result without hiding]

Now, we hide the plot of the question and the node by putting them on the discarded layer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{discard}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{discard}
    \path (2, 5) node (hw) {Hello World}; % or node[draw]
    \path[name path=phantom] plot coordinates { % or \draw
      (0, 2)
      (2, 5)
      (3, 7)
    };
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \draw[name path=circle] (2, 5) circle[radius=2];
  \draw[name intersections={of=phantom and circle}]
    (intersection-1) -- (hw.south west)
    -- (hw.north east) -- (intersection-2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with hiding]

Because the discarded layer is not added to the output file, the PDF file size shrinks from 11696 to 1198 bytes (both: `pdflatex` with `\pagestyle{empty}`).