# TikZ: How to split a tikzpicture into parts with a foreach-loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

[image]

If I have three parts of paths and nodes in a tikzpicture: what is the best way to split that up **with a foreach-loop**  into 3 tikzpictures, where only one part is showing? 
Like: 
[image], 
[image], 
[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \part in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={->, thin, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, text=black, inner sep=0.5pt, very near start},
]
% 1:
\draw[mystyle] (140:1.2) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{1};

% 2:
\draw[mystyle, purple] (163:0.9) -- +(0.9,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{2};

% 3: 
\draw[mystyle, red, rounded corners=3] (200:0.6) -- ++(-0.3,-0.3) -- ++(0.4,-0.4) node[mystyle, below]{3};
\node[fill=red, circle, minimum width=2mm] at (210:0.1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Idea: You could try to use the `beamer` class (also with `standalone`) and its overlay feature for this.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542668/194703), doesn't it? I agree with @MartinScharrer that the simplest way would be to use beamer, or better a beamer `standaloneframe` (from the `standalone` package) combined with the `overlay-beamer-styles` library.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  you're so fast I don't even have time to quot my own question!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `discard` layer of PGF for this as described in [tikz: construct a phantom path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405120). I wrapped it into a nice environment (which can't be nested).

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\let\showonlyend\relax

\newenvironment{showonly}[2]{%
\ifnum#1=#2\else%
\let\showonlyend\endpgfonlayer
\pgfonlayer{discard}\fi
}{%
\showonlyend
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{discard}

\begin{document}
\foreach \p in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={->, thin, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, text=black, inner sep=0.5pt, very near start},
]
% 1:
\begin{showonly}{\p}{1}
\draw[mystyle] (140:1.2) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{1};
\end{showonly}

% 2:
\begin{showonly}{\p}{2}
\draw[mystyle, purple] (163:0.9) -- +(0.9,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{2};
\end{showonly}

% 3: 
\begin{showonly}{\p}{3}
\draw[mystyle, red, rounded corners=3] (200:0.6) -- ++(-0.3,-0.3) -- ++(0.4,-0.4) node[mystyle, below]{3};
\node[fill=red, circle, minimum width=2mm] at (210:0.1) {};
\end{showonly}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if`:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \part in {1,...,3}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={->, thin, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, text=black, inner sep=0.5pt, very near start},
]
% 1:
\ifnum\part=1
    \draw[mystyle] (140:1.2) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{1};
\fi

% 2:
\ifnum\part=2
    \draw[mystyle, purple] (163:0.9) -- +(0.9,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{2};
\fi

% 3: 
\ifnum\part=3
    \draw[mystyle, red, rounded corners=3] (200:0.6) -- ++(-0.3,-0.3) -- ++(0.4,-0.4) node[mystyle, below]{3};
    \node[fill=red, circle, minimum width=2mm] at (210:0.1) {};
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

**== EDIT ==**

As @Martin Scharrer♦ says the answer above is not what wanted.
You can achieve that using opacity:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \a/\b/\c in {1/0/0, 0/1/0, 0/0/1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={->, thin, font=\sffamily\tiny, blue, text=black, inner sep=0.5pt, very near start},
]
% 1:
\draw[mystyle, opacity=\a] (140:1.2) -- +(0.6,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{1};

% 2:
\draw[mystyle, purple, opacity=\b] (163:0.9) -- +(0.9,0.05) node[mystyle, above]{2};

% 3: 
\draw[mystyle, red, rounded corners=3, opacity=\c] (200:0.6) -- ++(-0.3,-0.3) -- ++(0.4,-0.4) node[mystyle, below]{3};
\node[fill=red, circle, minimum width=2mm, opacity=\c] at (210:0.1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will simply skip the other parts and not reserve empty space, so that every picture only contains the current part. You could just create three separate picture environments instead to get the same result.I think the OP wants to have the parts not being displayed but the space still reserved.

Comment: The 2nd MWE looks interesting. It should be possible to incorporate a simplification using a pgfmathsetmacro. And then only `\foreach \part in {1,2,3}`

Comment: PS:  I used  `\pgfmathsetmacro\y{1 == \part ? 1 : 0}`
and then `\draw[..., opacity=\y] ...`

Comment: DPD, @cis: There might also be a way to use the 'use as bounding box' feature of TikZ/PGF together with discarding the draw path afterwards, so nothing is drawn. The opacity will actually draw something, but in a way that it is not visible.